Testing python code with different byteorder / endianness
I'm writing some python code that is sensitive to the byteorder / endianness. I want to ensure my unit tests are run in both byteorders.
I'm currently running my tests on  x86_64 Linux, which has little byteorder. What is the easiest way to run my python unit tests with big byteorder?

Unless you're using the struct module, I don't see how Python itself would care about endianness. Also, please add a minimal reproducible example.

You will need either a virtual machine with opposite byte order, or rent a cloud provider or something similar. Python makes no difference in this. It is impossible to run python in a different byte order than the underlying system

Try to install Solaris on VMWare.
